# table layout - foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a design table for foreach .

The following code generates output layout 1. I want output layout 2.

Is it possible?

```
$no=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2))
{
    $CATEGORY[$row['NAME']][]=$row['MONTH'];
}
foreach($CATEGORY as $key => $CATEGORY)
{
    echo " <tr>
    <td>$no</td>
    <td>".$key.'</td>
    <td> <ol>';
    $no=$no+1;
    foreach($CATEGORY as $CODE)
    { 
        echo' <li>'. $CODE.'<br></li>';
    }
    echo "</ol></td><td></td></tr>";
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not a good practice. But you can give a try to below code:

```
    $old = 0;
    echo '<table>';
    foreach($CATEGORY as $key => $CATEGORY)
    {
        foreach($CATEGORY as $CODE)
        { 
        echo "<tr>";

           if($old == 1)
           {
              echo "<td></td>
              <td></td>";
           }
           else
           {
              echo "<td>".$no."</td>
              <td>".$key."</td>";
              $old = 1;
          }

        echo "<td>";
        echo $CODE."<br>";
        echo "</td><td></td></tr>";
        }
        $old = 0;
        $no=$no+1;
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: if($old == 1) - undefined variable : old , but table work like layout 2

Comment: if I want to show total value,and appearing in the column total how to add to the array in foreach ex :$row['TOTAL']