# foreach multidimensional array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

from my question

[table layout - foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242776/table-layout-foreach)

this is source code

```
<table>

<tr>
<th>No</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>

$no=1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2))
    {
        $CATEGORY[$row['NAME']][]=$row['MONTH'];
    }
    $old = 0;

    foreach($CATEGORY as $key => $CATEGORY)
    {
        foreach($CATEGORY as $CODE)
        { 
        echo "<tr>";

           if($old == 1)
           {
              echo "<td></td>
              <td></td>";
           }
           else
           {
              echo "<td>".$no."</td>
              <td>".$key."</td>";
              $old = 1;
          }

        echo "<td>";
        echo $CODE."<br>";
        echo "</td><td></td></tr>";
        }
        $old = 0;
        $no=$no+1;
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

If I want to show total value,and appearing in the column total how to add to the array in `foreach` ex: `$row['TOTAL']`

Comment: Can you `print_r($CATEGORY)`? And show the result to me

Comment: Array([0] => Sept )

I put at the end after </table>

Comment: Give me the result of `$row` when used `print_r()`

Comment: Array ([id_name] => 1 [id_name] => 1 [id_month] => 8 [id_month] => 8 [name] => John [Month] => August)
Array ([id_name] => 2 [id_name] => 2 [id_month] => 9 [id_month] => 9 [name] => Adam [Month] => Sept)

Comment: So you want to make a table to display the name and the dates of a user?

Comment: I just want to display column TOTAL, from this query  $CATEGORY[$row['NAME']][]=$row['MONTH']; I just display name and month..I want add column total

Comment: Total value of ?  months? or user?

Comment: column total from my table value (no_value, id_name, id_month, total)

Comment: Try this `$CATEGORY[$row['NAME']][]= [$row['MONTH'], $row['TOTAL']];` change inside your `while loop`

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion #should i change or add something in for each, total show at array, but error when displayed

Comment: Can you `print_r($CATEGORY)` again after the `while` loop then after print_r()  type `exit;`

Comment: http://s16.postimg.org/airnpizx1/Capture.jpg 
http://s18.postimg.org/3rnsnm2ah/Capture2.jpg

Comment: Array ( [Adam] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Jan [1] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Feb [1] => 20 ) ) [John] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => March [1] => 0 ) ) )

Comment: output from prin screen code : http://s2.postimg.org/ctd8ns3ft/Capture3.jpg

Comment: Try my answer. If it works

Answer (score 1):

I get it now.

```
<table>

 <tr>
  <th>No</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Month</th>
  <th>Total</th>
 </tr>

 <?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2))
    {
      $CATEGORY[]=['id_month' => $row['id_month'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'month' => $row['month'], 'total' => $row['total'];
    }

    foreach($CATEGORY as $key => $val) {
       echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$val['id_month'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$val['name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$val['month'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$val['total'].'</td>';
       echo '</tr>';
    }
 ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: maybe you have two names in your database.

Comment: Yes it will duplicate try to observe your data's in your database. They have the same name.

Comment: yes, at db there is duplicate...but I just wan to show name once...at my code...it just display name once....

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the array to calculate total, each iteration you add the value to the initial total variable.

```
$data = [
   ['id' => 1,'cost' => 10],
   ['id' => 1,'cost' => 10],
   ['id' => 1,'cost' => 10]
];
$total = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $value){
 $total +=$value['cost'];

}
echo $total; // 30
```

This how you would calculate the total or you could also do it in your query.
Just adapt to your needs and it should solve your problem, you are almost there.